# Use dynamic (variable) string as regex pattern in R

Tags: r, regex, dynamic, nested, data.table

I have a data.table DT_words (large dimension):

```
DT_words <- data.table(word = c('word1', 'word2', 'word3','word4'))
```

I have another data.table DT_strings which contains a column with a large number of strings

```
DT_strings <- data.table(string = c('string1 made of word1', 'string2 made of word2 and word2 and word3 and word1ly', 'string3 made of word1 and word2'))
```

for each word in DT_word, i'd like to count the total number of occurrences in all of the strings in DT_string and save that value as a column in DT_word.
I am using for-loops, and it looks ugly.

I have tried using lapply and mapply but to no avail, since the function requires an internal input.

Here is the for-loop that words (but it takes a really long time and it's ugly)

```
require(stringr)

for (i in 1:nrow(DT_words))
{
   DT_words$word_count[i] <-  sum(str_count(DT_strings$string, 
                                  paste0(c("\\b("),paste(DT_words[i, .(word)]),c(")\\b"))))
}
```

I know the format is more of a data.frame but since I'm using a loop, it doesn't really matter, does it?
anyways, I was wondering if I could use apply in data.table and get rid of this ugliness.

desires output would be:

```
> DT_words
    word word_count
1: word1          2
2: word2          3
3: word3          1
4: word4          0
```

Edit: I edited DT_strings to include more examples of word matching. I'm only interested in matching whole word, hence the regex syntax must somehow be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your words are indeed just separated by a space, I would split them to columns, convert to long format and then, run a binary join combined with `by = .EACHI`, e.g., using your data:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)                       
DT_strings[, tstrsplit(string, " ", fixed = TRUE)] %>% 
  melt(., measure.vars = names(.), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  .[DT_words, on = .(value = word), .N, by = .EACHI]
#    value N
# 1: word1 2
# 2: word2 3
# 3: word3 1
# 4: word4 0
```

---

P.S.

I've used `fixed = TRUE` for speed as I assumed there is always once space between each word. In case the # of spaces varies, you'll need to use `tstrsplit(string, "\\s+")` instead which will be probably slower.

Comment: Wow. Such a beautiful of doing it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using the `tidyverse` suite of packages.

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

DT_words$word_count <- map_int(paste0("\\b", DT_words$word,"\\b"),
   ~ str_count(DT_strings$string, .x) %>% sum)
```

An alternative which does not use `purrr`:

```
DT_words$word_count <- vapply(paste0("\\b", DT_words$word, "\\b"), function(x) {
  sum(str_count(DT_strings$string, x))
}, 0)
```

Comment: what's `as.character` for

Comment: If you're converting `DT_words`, you should include that in your answer. FWIW you probably don't need to do this conversion. As OP specifically mentioned `DT_words` has large dimension, efficiency is probably important for his case :)

Comment: Yes, indeed.... there would be over 20,000 DT_words and nearly 500,000 DT_strings entries. I'm hoping to find a data.table + apply solution

Comment: Admittedly, I don't know data.table - but `apply` (and probably `map` - for that matter) are considered "loop-hiding" not "loop avoiding".  I don't think there is a way to avoid the loop in R - You can get the same basic effect using `vapply` instead of `map_int` - and that might be faster.

Comment: @MelissaKey your solution doesn't work because it also counts the words as part of another word. Try it with DT_strings <- data.table(string = c('string1 made of word1', 'string2 made of word2 and word2 and word3 and word2ly', 'string3 made of word1 and word2')) and you'll know what I mean. Word2 should be counted only three times but in this example it will be counted four times. That's why i needed to provide the redex syntax to only count the whole words.

Comment: Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that what you call strings and words are coming from natural language, I suggest the following base R solution that possibly runs faster. The point will be what you have to separate the different words in the strings, but it is easy to adapt the 'strsplit' to other separators.

```
s <- c('string1 made of word1', 'string2 made of word2 and word2 and word3', 'string3 made of word1 and word2')
w <- c('word1', 'word2', 'word3','word4')

z <- as.data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(s,' '))))
z[z$Var1 %in% w,]

#   Var1 Freq
#7 word1    2
#8 word2    3
#9 word3    1
```